# XML/XSL - Muenchian method for nesting groups within groups

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, transform, adobe-indesign

I'm working on an XSL Stylsheet where Students are grouped in this order:

**college->level->department->chair->concentration->student**

So basically the structure would be "groups within groups". Let me know if the following makes sense. Let me know if you need clarification!

This is the original XML that I'm trying to transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dataroot>
    <student>
        <name_sort>Doe, John</name_sort>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <level>Undergrad</level>
        <concentration>Studio Art</concentration>
        <college>College 1</college>
        <department>Department 1</department>
       <chair>Chair Name</chair>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name_sort>James, Lisa</name_sort>
        <name>Lisa James</name>
        <level>Undergrad</level>
        <concentration>Studio Art</concentration>
        <college>College 1</college>
        <department>Department 1</department>
       <chair>Chair Name</chair>
    </student>
<dataroot>
```

XML Output with applied XSL stylesheet:

```
<Root>

<!-- Group by College -->

<college>College 1</college>

<!-- Group by Level -->

<level>Undergraduate</level>

<!-- Group by Department -->

<department>Department 1</department>

<!-- Group by Chair -->

<chair>Chair Name</chair>

 <!-- Group by Concentration -->

<concentration>Studio Art</concentration>

<!-- List Students with matching concentration under parent groups -->

<student>
    <name>John Doe</name>
</student>

<student>
    <name>Lisa James</name>
</student>

<!-- Repeat loop -->

</Root>
```

This is my attempt, but students don't group correctly. Some students that are "undegraduate" show up under "graduate" and some concentration groups are duplicated...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- Keys for grouping -->
<xsl:key name="colleges" match="student" use="college"/>
<xsl:key name="levels" match="student" use="level"/>
<xsl:key name="departments" match="student" use="department"/>
<xsl:key name="chairs" match="student" use="chair"/>
<xsl:key name="concentrations" match="student" use="concentration"/>

<xsl:template match="/dataroot">
    <Root>
        <xsl:for-each select="student[generate-id() = generate-id(key('colleges', college)[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="college" order="ascending"/>

            <xsl:for-each select="key('colleges', college)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('levels', level)[1])]">
                <xsl:sort select="level" order="ascending"/>

                <college><xsl:value-of select="college"/></college>
                <xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>

                <level><xsl:value-of select="level"/> degree recipients</level>
                <xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>

                <xsl:for-each select="key('levels', level)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('departments', department)[1])]">
                    <xsl:sort select="department" order="ascending"/>
                    <department><xsl:value-of select="department"/></department>
                    <xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>

                    <xsl:for-each select="key('departments', department)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('chairs', chair)[1])]">
                        <xsl:sort select="chair" order="ascending"/>
                        <chair><xsl:value-of select="chair"/></chair>
                        <xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>

                        <xsl:for-each select="key('chairs', chair)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('concentrations', concentration)[1])]">
                            <xsl:sort select="concentration" order="ascending"/>
                            <concentration><xsl:value-of select="concentration"/></concentration>
                            <xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>

                            <xsl:for-each select="key('concentrations', concentration)">
                                <xsl:sort select="name_sort" order="ascending"/>
                                <student>
                                    <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
                                    <xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>
                                </student>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy with XSLT 2 or 3 to nest `xsl:for-each-group` the way you try it with `xsl:for-each` but with XSLT 1 and Muenchian grouping you will need to have the second level key include the first level key with e.g.

```
<xsl:key name="colleges" match="student" use="college"/>
<xsl:key name="levels" match="student" use="concat(college, '|', level)"/>
```

and use e.g.

```
 <xsl:for-each select="key('colleges', college)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('levels', concat(college, '|', level))[1])]">
```

and then you need to use the same approach with the third level key

```
<xsl:key name="departments" match="student" use="concat(department, '|', college, '|', level)"/>
```

and

```
 <xsl:for-each select="key('levels', concat(college, '|', level))[generate-id() = generate-id(key('departments', concat(department, '|', college, '|', level))[1])]">
```

and so on.

Comment: Sorry this script is for InDesign CC. InDesign doesn't support XSL 2.0 syntax unfortunately! :(

Comment: @user1526521, follow the approach I outlined, you get rather large key expressions with all the concatenations but it is the way to go with XSLT 1: http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200101/msg00070.html.

Comment: Yeah definitely long key expressions, but  it's okay. Yeah, unfortunately I'm working with XSL 1.0. Wish I could use xsl:for-each-group haha. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a single key that concatenates all needed parent groupings. No need for multiple nested `for:each` calls. Run needed sort inside the `<xsl:apply-templates>`. However, you would need a grouping container element as a child to root in case you have many groupings. Below uses `<students>` with an adjusted XML for demonstration.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dataroot>
    <student>
        <name_sort>Doe, John</name_sort>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <level>Undergrad</level>
        <concentration>Studio Art</concentration>
        <college>College 1</college>
        <department>Department 1</department>
       <chair>Chair Name</chair>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name_sort>James, Lisa</name_sort>
        <name>Lisa James</name>
        <level>Undergrad</level>
        <concentration>Economics</concentration>
        <college>College 1</college>
        <department>Department 1</department>
       <chair>Chair Name</chair>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name_sort>Doe, Jane</name_sort>
        <name>Jane Doe</name>
        <level>Undergrad</level>
        <concentration>Economics</concentration>
        <college>College 1</college>
        <department>Department 1</department>
       <chair>Chair Name</chair>
    </student>
</dataroot>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- single key for grouping -->
  <xsl:key name="concatkey" match="student" use="concat(college, level, department, chair, concentration)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/dataroot">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="student[generate-id() = generate-id(key('concatkey', 
                                               concat(college, level, department, chair, concentration)))]"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="student">
    <students>
      <xsl:copy-of select="college"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="level"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="department"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="chair"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="concentration"/>

      <xsl:for-each select="key('concatkey', concat(college, level, department, chair, concentration))">
        <student><xsl:copy-of select="name"/></student>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </students>
  </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output** [XSLT Fiddle DEMO](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKw3/1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <students>
    <college>College 1</college>
    <level>Undergrad</level>
    <department>Department 1</department>
    <chair>Chair Name</chair>
    <concentration>Economics</concentration>
    <student>
      <name>Lisa James</name>
    </student>
    <student>
      <name>Jane Doe</name>
    </student>
  </students>
  <students>
    <college>College 1</college>
    <level>Undergrad</level>
    <department>Department 1</department>
    <chair>Chair Name</chair>
    <concentration>Studio Art</concentration>
    <student>
      <name>John Doe</name>
    </student>
  </students>
</root>
```

Comment: As mentioned, I used a different XML source for demonstration. Your desired output (though XSLT did) had no root and seems to place all nodes as children to the root where multiple college/level/chair/etc. are siblings, making groups hard to decipher in output. Here same-parent students are grouped under specific `<students>`.